# What's the best Street Address Search service?

Tags: google-maps, virtual-earth, street-address

I'm impressed with the simplicity of Microsoft's Virtual Earth Street Address search service.

My requirement is to type rough address info with no comma separators into a simple text box, press a find button, wait a few seconds and then observe a result picklist.

I mocked up something [here](http://www.garyrusso.org/map.html) using the [virtual earth SDK](http://dev.live.com/virtualearth/sdk/).

Does Google Maps have a similar API?

Which street address search service is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

There is a bit of information in these related questions:

[How do you perform address validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134956/how-do-you-perform-address-validation)
[How to obtain longitude and latitude for a street address programmatically (and legally)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158474/how-to-obtain-longitude-and-latitude-for-a-street-address-programmatically-and)

Answer (score 2):

There's also the [yahoo maps API](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/)