# Is it possible to validate a postal address with Google Locations

Tags: java, regex, google-play-services, google-places-api

Is it possible to validate a postal address for its completeness? Meaning, I need to grab `autocomplete` values using `Google Places` and after a user select an address I need to validate it if it contains a house number and a postcode.

`Holderlinstrasse 12, 11070, Berlin, Germany` - is fine

`Holderlinstrasse Berlin, Germany` - is not

I haven't found any APIs to serve the purpose. I've considered regex, but this also doesn't sound like an easy way.

Any advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally considered a much more difficult task that you imagine. Legitimate street addresses are extremely hard to identify even by a human. Internationally cities have vastly different ways of expressing addresses and within special environments (like the US military and large business and government organisations) addresses may not have anything like a number, street name or territory.

[This closed SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134956/how-do-you-perform-address-validation) contains a fair discussion of some possibilities but there is no 100% solution.